# Why Angular method binding firing continiously?

Tags: angular, angular7

```
@Component({
  selector: 'calc',
  template: '<p *ngIf="isCalculatable()"></p>'
})
export class CalcComponent {
   isCalculatable(){
       console.log("yes");
       return true;
   }
}
```

When I use this component `<calc></calc>`, it writes "yes" to console continiously. I mean `isCalculatable()` method firing. So I am using this method so many times in my applicaitons. May this stuation be performance issue?

Comment: It can be a performance issue, yes. Don't bind complex functions or ones with side effects in your template (if you need to bind to such a function, save the result to a variable and bind to that instead).

Answer (score 0):

Angular watches over every components and its changes continuously... It keeps checking for the changes of the `ngIf` condition at a certain interval... Thats why when it changes to false the element is removed from dom automatically and is added again when the condition again evaluates to true.

Answer (score 0):

This method runs for every change detection of the component.